# Convert CHAR from INTEGER in java derby DB

Tags: sql, derby

In following query want to give integer value in else part.
If i give, error is:
Error code -1, SQL state 42X89: Types 'CHAR' and 'INTEGER' are not type compatible. Neither type is assignable to the other type.

```
select case
when ID = 1 then 'Issue'
when ID = 2 then 'Reload'
when ID = 3 then 'Redeem'
else ID
end
from TXN
where CARDNO = '10001'
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just CAST that ID to `VARCHAR()`

```
select case
when ID = 1 then 'Issue'
when ID = 2 then 'Reload'
when ID = 3 then 'Redeem'
else CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(2))
end
from TXN
where CARDNO = '10001'
```

Comment: Still error like; Error code -1, SQL state 42846: Cannot convert types 'INTEGER' to 'VARCHAR'.

Comment: what is the data type of  CARDNO ??

Comment: CARDNO datatype is VARCHAR

Comment: what about ID? can u provide the table structure?

Comment: if ID is CHAR instaed of `ID=1` try `ID='1'` like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33124/discussion-between-nithesh-and-manoj)

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`:

```
select case
when ID = 1 then 'Issue'
when ID = 2 then 'Reload'
when ID = 3 then 'Redeem'
else CAST(ID AS CHAR(10))
end
from TXN
where CARDNO = '10001'
```

Compatible types for cast: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html

Answer (score 0):

cast to char is fine, but it will have all the space padding, so after cast to char you then have to cast the char to varchar and then RTRIM.